# Please help me with this ruccurence equation 3t(n/3)+n/2

Tags: algorithm

3t(n/3) + n/2
i must resolve this with iterative method. Can anyone help me?

the last step that i made is that:

3^k T(n/3^k) + summ[from i=0 to k-1] of 3^i * n/2^i+1

i am blocked here

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a homework problem, I can refer you to a source that should help: [Master's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))